# WPF Datagrid: copy additional rows to clipboard

Tags: wpf, datagrid, clipboard

I am working with the WPF Datagrid and I am trying to enhance/change the copy & paste mechanism.

When the user selects some cells and then hit CTRL + C, the underlying controls is able to catch the **CopyingRowClipboardContent** event.

```
 this.mainDataGrid.CopyingRowClipboardContent 
              += this.DatagridOnCopyingRowClipboardContent;
```

In this method, some cells are added to both the header and the rows, hence resulting in a "wider" grid.

```
    private void DatagridOnCopyingRowClipboardContent(
        object sender, 
        DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs dataGridRowClipboardEventArgs)
    {
        // this is fired every time a row is copied
        var allContent = dataGridRowClipboardEventArgs.ClipboardRowContent;

        allContent.Insert(0, new DataGridClipboardCellContent(
                                            null, 
                                            this.mainDataGrid.Columns[0], 
                                            "new cell"));
    }
```

At this point I am stuck because I am trying to add an additional row **before** the header and **two after** the last row (see image below).

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Please note I am not interested in an MVVM way of doing it here.

[image]

Comment: Sweet pic how did you draw it?

Comment: Thanks. Old school pen & paper ==> iPhone picture ==> crop and adjust with Paint.Net. The whole takes probably less than a minute. The fact that I use my right hand is incidental. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that might help you.
This snippet is mainly used to retrieve all of your selected data, including headers (I removed the `RowHeaders` part since you apparently don't need it).
If you have any question please let me know. I left a few part with comments written in capital letters: this is where you should add your own data
The good part of this approach is that it directly works with your `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` and NOT the `DataGridCell`. The main reason being: if you use `DataGridCell` on a formatted number for example, you will NOT get the actual value, but just the formatted one (say your source is 14.49 and your `StringFormat` is N0, you'll just copy 14 if you use a "regular" way)

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Handles DataGrid copying with headers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnCopyingDataGrid(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // First step: getting the coordinates list of all cells selected
        IList<Tuple<int, int>> cellsCoordinatesList = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        HashSet<int> rowList = new HashSet<int>();
        HashSet<int> columnList = new HashSet<int>();
        foreach (System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellInfo cell in this.SelectedCells)
        {
            int column = cell.Column.DisplayIndex;
            int row = this.Items.IndexOf(cell.Item);
            cellsCoordinatesList.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(row, column));
            if (!rowList.Contains(row))
            {
                rowList.Add(row);
            }
            if (!columnList.Contains(column))
            {
                columnList.Add(column);
            }
        }

        // Second step: Create the table to copy/paste
        object[,] arrayToBeCopied = new object[rowList.Count, columnList.Count + 1];
        IList<string> colHead = this.ColumnHeaders.Cast<object>().Select(h => h.ToString()).ToList();
        for (int row = 0; row < arrayToBeCopied.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < arrayToBeCopied.GetLength(1); column++)
            {
                if (row == 0)
                {
                    arrayToBeCopied[row, column] = colHead[columnList.ElementAt(column - 1)];
                }
                else
                {
                    arrayToBeCopied[row, column] = // WHATEVER YOU WANT TO PUT IN THE CLIPBOARD SHOULD BE HERE. THIS SHOULD GET SOME PROPERTY IN YOUR ITEMSSOURCE

                }
            }
        }

        // Third step: Converting it into a string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // HERE, ADD YOUR FIRST ROW BEFORE STARTING TO PARSE THE COPIED DATA

        for (int row = 0; row < arrayToBeCopied.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < arrayToBeCopied.GetLength(1); column++)
            {
                sb.Append(arrayToBeCopied[row, column]);
                if (column < arrayToBeCopied.GetLength(1) - 1)
                {
                    sb.Append("\t");
                }
            }
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }

        // AND HERE, ADD YOUR LAST ROWS BEFORE SETTING THE DATA TO CLIPBOARD

        DataObject data = new DataObject();
        data.SetData(DataFormats.Text, sb.ToString());

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
    }
```

Comment: This is quite interesting. So your approach is to actually completely bypass the mechanism within the grid.

Comment: Exactly, I redefined the copy/paste behavior because as I explained above, the default one does not quite fulfill my needs (which I'd consider being natural, copying the values and not juste what's written on screen) :/

Comment: How did you override the default copy command behaviour with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to copy the content into e.g. Excel later?
If so, here's what I did:

```
/// <summary>
/// Copy the data from the data grid to the clipboard
/// </summary>
private void copyDataOfMyDataGridToClipboard(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save selection
    int selectedRow = this.myDataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;

    // Select data which you would like to copy
    this.myDataGrid.MultiSelect = true;
    this.myDataGrid.SelectAll();

    // Prepare data to be copied (that's the interesting part!)
    DataObject myGridDataObject = this.myDataGrid.GetClipboardContent();
    string firstRow = "FirstRowCommentCell1\t"+ this.someDataInCell2 +"..\r\n";
    string lastTwoRows = "\r\nBottomLine1\t" + yourvariables + "\r\nBottomLine2";
    string concatenatedData = firstRow + myGridDataObject.GetText() + lastTwoRows;

    // Copy into clipboard
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(concatenatedData);

    // Restore settings
    this.myDataGrid.ClearSelection();
    this.myDataGrid.MultiSelect = false;

    // Restore selection
    this.myDataGrid.Rows[selectedRow].Selected = true;
}
```

In my case I had some static header's which could be easily concatenated with some variables. Important to write are the `\t` for declaring another cell, `\r\n` declares the next row

Answer (score 0):

I realize this an older post, but I post this solution for completeness. I could not find a more recent question on copying datagrid rows to clipboard. Using Clipboard.SetData belies the ClipboardRowContent intention.

For my needs, I'm re-pasting back into the e.ClipboardRowContent the row I would like. The cell.Item is all the information I need for each selected row.

Hint: I was getting duplicates without doing an e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear(); after using the e.ClipboardRowContent . I was clearing before and using DataGrid.SelectedItems to build the rows.

```
private void yourDataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender,    DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
{
var dataGridClipboardCellContent = new List<DataGridClipboardCellContent>(); 

string prevCell = "";
string curCell = ""; 

foreach (DataGridClipboardCellContent cell in e.ClipboardRowContent)
{
    //Gives you access item.Item or item.Content here
    //if you are using your struct (data type) you can recast it here curItem = (yourdatatype)item.Item;        
    curItem = cell.Item.ToString(); 

    if (curCell != prevCell)
        dataGridClipboardCellContent.Add(new DataGridClipboardCellContent(item, item.Column, curCell)); 

    prevCell = curCell;  

}
e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();

//Re-paste back into e.ClipboardRowContent, additionally if you have modified/formatted rows to your liking
e.ClipboardRowContent.AddRange(dataGridClipboardCellContent);
```

}